# is there a way to compare two excels and perform operations like insert row as per comparison?

Tags: python, excel, algorithm, dataframe

I'm trying to solve a problem using python.
I have two excels let's say Old_excel and New_excel.
New_excel is kind of a version of Old_excel such that few rows in New_excel have been inserted which are not present in Old_excel and fews rows are deleted from New_excel.

[Example of Old_excel and New_excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lzjv.png)

I am looking for a solution which can insert a blank row in Old_excel if new row has been inserted in New_excel and insert blank row in New_excel if row has been deleted from New_excel as mentioned below:-

[The two excels should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdCKF.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: Yellow color in output excel examples is to help viewer understand the problem statement quickly. Hence not required in solution.

Comment: in your code, how do u find/identify the matched rows?

Comment: I have tried using align and compare function of pandas dataframe

Comment: Maybe someone has a better idea, but you could do worse than serializing each row to text and computing the longest common subsequence using difflib.

Comment: in `and insert blank row in New_excel if row has been deleted from New_excel as mentioned below:-` ... do u actually mean `deleted from Old_excel` ? (please [edit] to update the question)

Comment: It means if a row is present in old excel and in new excel it's not there (i.e. got deleted from new excel) then insert a blank row in new excel w.r.t the location of row in old excel . I hope it clears the doubt. Kindly let me know if there is any other query.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install `pandas` and `openpyxl` packages.

Then we will find differences between two files. This is just reading the rows and hashing them:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('old.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', header=None, dtype=str)
df2 = pd.read_excel('new.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', header=None, dtype=str)
h1 = df1.apply(lambda x: hash(str(x.values)), axis=1)
h2 = df2.apply(lambda x: hash(str(x.values)), axis=1)

ch2 = h1[~h1.isin(h2)]
ch1 = h2[~h2.isin(h1)]
```

Now we will read the excel files once again (in order to preserve original styling) and change the style of relevant cells:

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="fdff32")
wb1 = load_workbook('old.xlsx')  
wb2 = load_workbook('new.xlsx')  

ws1 = wb1.active
ws2 = wb2.active

# if number of rows is different
while ws2.max_row>ws1.max_row:
    ws1.append([None])
while ws1.max_row>ws2.max_row:
    ws2.append([None])

# define highltning style 
fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="fdff32")

for ix in ch1.index:
    for cell in list(ws1.rows)[ix]:
        cell.fill = fill
for ix in ch2.index:
    for cell in list(ws2.rows)[ix]:
        cell.fill = fill
wb1.save('old_.xlsx') 
wb2.save('new_.xlsx')
```

Comment: Go on, show us how it looks after working it all out! 

Comment: Yellow stripes on the changed lines ;)

Comment: Thank you for trying but this solution does not insert blank rows as per comparison.

Comment: It should. Please provide your input examples.

Comment: This sample code may not work on ur files, but it does on the answer's (self) example files. would u mind sharing some sample files to (help the helpers) test the solution.. ?

Comment: I tested on same example given in problem statement.

Comment: Blank row insertion should happen if row is missing in corresponding excel. If you will compare the output of this code with the output mentioned in problem statement line by line you will see the difference.

Comment: Dear Nitesh, Yes u r correct. we need the line by line comparison. U can share the sample file to help us looking into it. /(^_^)

Comment: Surely I would have shared the sample excel files but unfortunately excel files can't be attached on this platform. That's why I have shared the images of excel samples.